# Action bar single icon with two images while clicking

Tags: android

I have one icon in action bar. when I click that I want to change its icon image and again click that same icon, then I want the old icon image.

```
if(id == R.id.action_edit  ) {
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
    item.setIcon(item.isChecked() ? R.drawable.ic_save : R.drawable.ic_edit);
    return true;
}
```

in this code i done that one. i want toast also while clicking, Please help me anyone. Thanks in advance

Comment: You just want to display a toast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
if(id == R.id.action_edit  ) {
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
    item.setIcon(item.isChecked() ? R.drawable.ic_save : R.drawable.ic_edit);
    if(item.isChecked())
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changed to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changed to edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
if(id == R.id.action_edit  ) {
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
    item.setIcon(item.isChecked() ? R.drawable.ic_save : R.drawable.ic_edit);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Toast message!",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I want two toasts, while first click edit toast and second click save toast.

Comment: Put one toast to your clicklistener ,then put your second toast to your save method. It will be easy to you.